# TopLevel instance never closed even when .destroy()?

Tags: python, tkinter, instance

I was doing a big HMI using tkinter with multiple windows when some button are clicked.

I found out that when I try to close a second window (TopLevel of Tk main window), the instance of it never close. :(

Here's an **exemple ** that represent well my issue. (this is not my real code, my real code do other stuff).

```
import tkinter as tk

global secondWindow

class SecondWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("250x250")
        self.title('second window')

        lab = tk.Label(self, text="exemple")
        lab.pack()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onclosing)

    def onclosing(*args) :
        global secondWindow
        #do other stuff and 
        secondWindow.destroy()



class MainWindow(tk.Tk) :

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        global secondWindow

        self.title('exemple')
        self.geometry('250x250')

        secondWindow = None

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="create a new instance of Toplevel", command=self.button_clicked)

        self.button.pack()

        self.isIns()


    def button_clicked(self, *args) :
        global secondWindow
        secondWindow = SecondWindow()

    def isIns(self, *args) :
        global secondWindow

        print(isinstance(secondWindow, SecondWindow))

        self.after(500, self.isIns)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

If you try to run this code, click on the button to create an instance of TopLevel and click on the cross on the secondWindow, the instance is still "up"

I would like to when I close the second window the instance is destroyed (output should be : False, False... True, True... and False again).

Comment: It's not clear exactly what is failing here - does the second window actually disappear from the screen when closed, or not?  The `isinstance()` check is expected to fail here - `secondWindow` is going to continue being an instance of `SecondWindow`, even if it no longer represents an actual window on the screen.  You'd need to explicitly set it to None in `onclosing()` to change that behavior.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you ! It worked ! I thought that .destroy will destroy the instance of SecondWindow, but as you said, it just destroy the window and not the instance of it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one have the same issue, just modify "onClosin" function with :

```
def onclosing(*args) :
    global secondWindow
    #do other stuff and 
    secondWindow.destroy()
    secondWindow = None
```

Big thank you for @jasonharper for helping me with this !